# Reverse order of list items with JS not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an unordered list that I have reversed with javascript. My script works but the list is duplicated. The page renders with the original list plus the output of twhat my js is doing. How can I make it only render once?  Should I rewrite with jQuery and use .detach() ?  Below is my code:

```
var navList = $('ul.menu');
var navListItems = list.children('li');
navlist.append(navListItems.get().reverse());
```

Answer (score 1):

Just typos in variable names :)

```js
var navList = $('ul.menu');
var navListItems = navList.children('li');
navList.append(navListItems.get().reverse());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li>item1</li>
  <li>item2</li>
  <li>item3</li>
  <li>item4</li>
  <li>item5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're appending the items to a list that already has items.  I suggest clearing the list after you've stored an array of the items.  Then, you can start to append each item again.  See snippet below.

```js
var navMenu = document.getElementById("menu");
var navList = Array.from(navMenu.children);
navList.reverse().forEach( function(listItem){
  navMenu.append(listItem);
});
```

```html
<div>
  <p>List</p>
  <ul id="menu">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Edit: as per [freedomn-m](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2181514/freedomn-m)'s comment, the append function will "move" existing items instead of adding onto the list.  Removed the unnecessary `navMenu.innerHTML = "";` line.

Comment: OP is not appending new items.  `$().append` ( / .append() if you want to answer a jquery question with vanilla javascript) will *move* existing items.  Try your code without the `navMenu.innerHTML = "";` and it works just as well without duplicating items.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up.  Updated my answer.  The "append" name kind of throws me off, as my assumption is that it's going to "add" instead of "move".  But it totally makes sense now.